# node.io : when the job is done, do it again

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, node.io

I'm building a **scraper** with [node.io](http://node.io/).

The page I want to **scrape** has new content every minute. I would like to run my job again and again every minute.
(Ok I could do that with a bash script, but I would like to stay in javascript)
This is a basic job :

```
var nodeio = require('node.io'), options = {timeout: 10};

exports.job = new nodeio.Job(options, {
    input: ['hello', 'foobar', 'weather'],
    run: function (keyword) {
        this.getHtml('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword), function (err, $) {
            var results = $('#resultStats').text.toLowerCase();
            this.emit(keyword + ' has ' + results);
        });
    }
});
```

How could I do that ? I'm a beginner in node.js, i tried setInterval around the job (: without success.

Comment: what about using while(true) and setTimeout(60000)

Comment: @user1291492 : the job never starts

Comment: So have you even tested your code? I see there are a bunch of tutorials on the node.io site. maybe that would be the place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (run with "node`<myfile.js`>" instead of "node.io`<myfile.js`>"):

```
var nodeio = require('node.io'), options = {timeout: 10};
var job = {
    input: ['hello', 'foobar', 'weather'],
    run: function (keyword) {
        this.getHtml('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword), function (err, $) {
        var results = 'test';//$('#resultStats').text.toLowerCase();
        this.emit(keyword + ' has ' + results);
      });
    }
};

setInterval(function(){
    nodeio.start(new nodeio.Job(options, job), options, function(){});
}, 5000);
```

The problem you were running into is the following block of code in node.io that exits node when you don't provide a callback when running the job:

```
//Default behaviour is to exit once the job is complete
callback = callback || function (err) {
    if (err) {
        utils.status.error(err);
    }
    process.exit();
};
```